# .htacess is not redirecting to 404 page with hide page extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this code,

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I know you use this code! What is your problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what is the problem in your case if you are doing in local server you have to add project name before the file name.

Please replace the below at .htaccess file.

File-.htacess
ErrorDocument 404 projectname/404.php

If server is live the you can use your rules.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php